# How to add a information section in swagger php

Tags: swagger-ui

I am trying to integrate the swagger PHP with readme and need to integrate an information section like this picture below [image]

This looks like it is a reamde.io callout section  but maybe this can be done with swagger aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a readme Callout section that can be added through swagger with HTML code copied from inspect code.